# How are friend pairs similar in terms of personality and individual differences?

Tags: social-psychology, personality

Lay psychology holds different opinions on whether having similar or different personalities promotes friendships between people. A case in point may be the conflicting idioms of "birds of a feather flock together" versus "opposites attract". Which one of them is true?

How does similarity in personality affect becoming friends? Are there certain personality traits that correlate positively or negatively between friends?

Comment: The question can't be properly answered as it is too broad and based on a premise of common folklore rather than science